# WPF custom grid not showing content

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a control, which I have inherited from Grid

```
<Grid x:Class="User_Controls.CustomGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
         >

<TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

The code behind is, at the moment, blank

```
 public partial class CustomGrid : Grid
{
public CustomGrid(){}    
}
```

I have an instance of CustomGrid inside another grid, on a page.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
            <src:LiveTile  x:Name="liveTile1" />    
        </Grid>
```

When I run the project, the value in the textfield isn't displayed. I've tried taking the control out of the parent grid, messing with fonts and vertical/horizontal alignments.

any idea why I cant see the value?

Comment: What happens if you play with the TextBlock Grid.Column and Grid.Row properties?

Comment: nothing. I've added a row/column definition and set the textblock row/col.

Comment: hmm... not too familiar with inheritance and WPF controls....  I am guessing that LiveTile is where the CustomGrid is defined?

Comment: I think i've sorted it. If I create a class that inherits grid, with no XAML, it displays the value. cheers for the help!